# autoPlay not working for stream

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flowplayer

I just setup flowplayer to play rtmp streams, but for some reason I need to click on the splash screen (Play stream text) to start the video even though I have autoPlay: true.

Is this a bug, or am I missing some configuration settings?

```
<!-- video -->
        <div id="stream" class="stream" style="width: 1000px; height: 650px; display: block;">
            Play stream text   
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         flowplayer("stream", "/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {

            clip: {
                url: 'mystream',
                live: 'true',
                provider: 'rtmp',
                scaling: 'orig',
                autoPlay: true
            },

            plugins: {
                rtmp: {
                    url: '/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
                    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://mms.mysite.com/live/'
                }
            },

            canvas: {
                backgroundGradient: 'none'
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason is that the so called splash screen should not be used as the way you suggest. If you put anything between the div, or as the documents to use , it always becomes a click-able area and the autoPlay true will come into place only when the player being really loaded (after you clicked).

I think the better way to go for the splashscreen would to use the recommended way in the document: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/skinning/